# partition by in elixir broadway

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, broadway

I’am trying to use [`partition_by` option](https://hexdocs.pm/broadway/Broadway.html#module-ordering-and-partitioning) in [broadway](https://hexdocs.pm/broadway) so that messages of the same partition go to the same processor. I have actually 20 processors and the message data is from 0 to 9

```
    ....
     processors: [
              default: [
                  max_demand: 50,
                  concurrency: 20
                  
              ]        
     ],
     partition_by: &partition/1
     )
  end
    
  defp partition(msg) do
       msg.data 
  end

  def handle_message(_processor, msg, _ctx) do
    Logger.info "pid #{inspect(self())}"
    ...
    msg
  end
```

what is weird is when I added some logs inside the handle message callback to watch the processor PID, I always get the same processor PID for all incoming messages. But when I remove the `partition_by` line, I have different processor pids. Any ideas why partitioning didn’t work?

Comment: Because for partitioning to take place, `partition_by` option must be used, otherwise the messages go to random processors.

Comment: partition_by option is used but all the messages go to the same processor no matter the value of msg.data. 
What I expected is : all messages with msg.data = 1 go to the same processor 1, and if msg.data = 2, the messages go to processor 2 and so on.

Comment: This might help https://dev.to/woojiahao/open-source-deep-dive-broadway-part-2-inner-workings-of-broadway-4daf

Comment: It’s not guaranteed that _different_ IDs go to the different partitions. What is indeed guaranteed, is the messages with the same ID always go to the same processor. Try to limit a number of processors to 5 to see this effect.

Comment: i reduced the number of processors to 5, but all IDs go to the same processor regardless the number of processors

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing with the Broadway partitioning myself and it works exactly as expected, messages with the same partition key end up on the same producer instance (identified by PID). From what I see in your code and it's not clear what do you return from your `partition` method. You need to be aware that a number should be returned from there. If your `message.data` is a string or something else it is possible that you will end up in the same partition. If you don't have a number available in your message that you can use for partitioning you can help yourself with the built-in erlang method and hash the string (`:erlang.phash2/1`).